# Как реализовать автоскролл когда overflow-y: hiden;

Tags: javascript

Есть блок скроллбар скрыт. Нужно чтобы колесиком мыши можно было скролить. Как организовать такое на `javascript`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно попробовать [без JS](http://jsfiddle.net/WhmGw/) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    e = window.event || e;
    delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail))); 
    if (delta > 0) { $('div').text('up'); }
    else { $('div').text('down'); }
});
```

P.S. только проблемы в firefox'e так и не решил их, может кто как раз подскажет.

Фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/erthU/

Comment: это же jQuery

Comment: @Dikaz а jQuery уже не javascript ?

Comment: мне нужно на чистом javascript'e, еще не дошел до главы jQuery

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте начал бы читать с главы jQuery тк если не планируете писать серверные приложения на nodejs то для фронт-энда jQuery хватит с головой и забудете навсегда такие вещи как getElementById, document.getElementsByTag